# Detecting tap on a tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created a tabBarController programatically like below

```
let tabbarController = UITabBarController()
    let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
    let rewardsViewController = RewardsViewController()
    let moreViewController = NewMoreViewController()

    let homeNVc = UINavigationController()
    homeNVc.viewControllers = [homeViewController]

    let rewardsNVc = UINavigationController()
    rewardsNVc.viewControllers = [rewardsViewController]

    let moreNVc = UINavigationController()
    moreNVc.viewControllers = [moreViewController]

    tabbarController.viewControllers = [homeNVc, rewardsNVc, moreNVc]

    tabbarController.tabBar.items![0].title = NSLocalizedString("Dashboard", comment: "")
    tabbarController.tabBar.items![1].title = NSLocalizedString("Prämien", comment: "")
    tabbarController.tabBar.items![2].title = NSLocalizedString("Mehr", comment: "")
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabbarController
}
```

everyThing is working . I can move through tabs perfectrly, Now I have ta tableView in my homeViewController. Which I want to reload when ever user taps on first tab of my TabBarController. Even if user is already on that viewController I want to reload tableView.

So basically How can I detect that user tapped on first ViewController ?

please guide me thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your **homeViewController** you may need to implement this delegate method:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    //ask where it is first tab bar item 
    if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 0 {
        // your action, e.g.:
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

**NOTE**:

You need to have maintained your class like this:

**a)**

```
class YourTabBarController: UITabBarController { // inherit from UITabBarController
```

or this:

**b)**

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate { // set protocol
```

Comment: I made this code for Swift 3, so in case you copy-paste, you may need to correct some statements

Comment: self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex was the keypoint for me didSelectItem was not getting called so i used didSelectViewController. Is that okay ?

Answer (score 4):

Invoke UITabBarControllerDelegate and implement this method

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController,   didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController){

}
```

Comment: How am I going to detect which tab was tapped ?

Comment: Every tab is attached with a viewcontroller. In your question you write "So basically How can I detect that user tapped on first ViewController ?" So in this method you will get viewController. You can check viewController or its identifier, title etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the following delegate method,

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

        if item.title == "first tab name"{
            //Do your thing
    }
```

Comment: I have implemneted this method but its not being called. But didSelectViewController is getting called

Comment: It's not safe to test it against title. It's not right convention.

Answer (score 1):

I have written something similar recently. For consistency, I created one base class BaseTabBarViewController for each Tab I use. But take into account that if a tab was a navigation controller, the one that inherits from the BaseTabBarViewController is the root view controller.
This base class implements the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol. In viewDidLoad, we mark it as delegate.
In the delegate method(Objective-c, quite similar in swift 3):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {


if (tabBarController.selected == 0)
{
   // do what you need
```

Comment: Change it to `if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)`. No such property as `.selected`

Answer (score 0):

To get access to which tabBarItem was tapped override the following function in your custom class for UITabBarController

**Swift:**

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
   guard let index = tabBar.items?.index(of: item) else { return }

   // Do something with the index
}
```